# Recognizing Acronyms with LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding, cortana-skills-kit

What is the best way to recognize acronyms in either an utterance directly or as an option in an entity list? Acronyms where people would naturally say the letters and not say as a word.

Trying to recognize things like:

- IT (Information Technology)
- KPI (Key Performance Indicator)
- IOT (Internet of Things)

Adding a "feature" for these seems to work ok but Cortana will spell out weird things on the screen. For example, KPI added these exchangeable values: kbi,  kvi,  kp eye,  kb eye,  kv eye,  key performance indicator,  kp i,  key performance indicators,  kpis,  keep ya eyes,  kp eyes. Based these off what I saw Cortana recognizing. Is there a better way though? IT didn't work as well with this approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an Entity of type List, where you can define the canonical form and synonyms for that word.

So in your case, the canonical form will be Information Technology and IT a synonym.

[image]

Comment: The challenge with this approach would be that it won't be able to differentiate it with acronym IT. so if there is sentence like "it is a hell of a profession: IT " . It would recognize two entities

Comment: Yeah, that's the only caveat